# How to estimate the gradient of an argmin loss

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, gradient

Suppose we have a neural network $f_\theta(x)$, where $x$ is the input and $\theta$ is the network's parameters.

For each $\theta$, we can minimize $f_\theta(x)$ w.r.t. $x$ and obtain the minimum point $x^*(\theta):=\arg\min_x f_\theta(x)$.

My question is: how to estimate the gradient: $\frac{d x^*(\theta)}{d \theta}$ ?

I did some surveys and found this gradient (in fact any gradient) can be estimated by the [finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) technique. However, it is rather slow when $\theta$ includes many parameters, *e.g.*, $f_\theta$ is a large neural network.

Any possible approach is welcomed.

Comment: Argmin is not differentiable, so what gradient are you trying to estimate? It does not actually exist.

Comment: As far as I know, argmin is not differentiable means: for $x^*=\arg\min x$, $\frac{dx^*}{dx}$ is either $0$ or does not exist. However, here, I am interested in the gradient $\frac{dx^*}{d\theta}$. I am not sure whether this gradient exist. Any suggestion?